# What is the most efficient way to create a lobby django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a lobby that would be accessible by a link `game/gameID`. What i have is just a simple field in my db `playerNumber = models.IntegerField(default =0)`. When user is connected i increment `playerNumber` by 1. When the  player number is 2 i just render error page. But when user closes game page by some mistake, someone else can join instead of him. How would  reserve the page for only 2 users and make them able to come back if they left.

Comment: You should look at Django Sessions.

Answer (score 1):

You could maintain a [**`ManyToMany`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) relation like this:

```
import uuid

class Lobby(...):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    game_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    def is_occupied(self):
        return self.users.count() >= 2
```

Then in view, you can check if you can add user:

```
 def add_user_to_lobby(request, game_id):
     lobby = get_object_or_404(Lobby, game_id)
     if lobby.users.filter(pk=request.user.pk).exists():
          return redirect('game_page')
     elif not lobby.is_occupied():
         lobby.users.add(request.user)
         return redirect('game_page')
     else:
         return render(request, "error_page.html")
```